# Strange design of core.sync.condition in D

Tags: concurrency, d

In the D programming language, class `Mutex` has shared and non-shared versions of its methods. This is logical — mutex is shared between threads. But class `Condition` doesn't have shared methods at all. Why? Maybe I missed something, but it's very strange for me, because such code doesn't work:

```d
class Foo {
    private Mutex mtx;
    private Condition cnd;

    shared this() {
        mtx = new Mutex(this); // error: no constructor Mutex(shared Object)
        cnd = new Condition(mtx); // error: no constructor Condition(shared Mutex)
    }
}
```

Please enlighten me)

Answer (score 0):

`shared` is such a strange beast, basically `Mutex` only has constructores that takes shared objects that are of `Mutex` itself, which Foo isn't.

`Condition` has no constructor that takes a `shared(Mutex)`.

Basically you can work around it with this:

```
class Foo {
    private Mutex mtx;
    private Condition cnd;

    shared this() {
        mtx = cast(shared)new Mutex(cast() this);
        cnd = cast(shared)new Condition(cast() mtx);
    }
}
```

Just because a constructor is `shared` like `this() shared` then it doesn't really apply to anything passed to it and basically it's just for its body AFAIK.

However to elaborate on the code above.

`cast()` will cast away any attributes that are applied to the type ex. `shared` which will allow you to pass it to the constructors.

Because the constructor of `Foo` is shared then we need to cast `Mutex` and `Condition` back to `shared` else we cannot assign them to `mtx` and `cnd` which are `shared` because of the constructor.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I definitely can use such workarounds, but at first it looks like a dirty hack (and it *really* is a dirty hack), and at second I don't sure that casts with adding/throwing away of `shared` attribute (and `const`, for example) are correct.

Comment: It is the correct way unfortunately to cast away shared when you have to assign etc. as strange as it is, hence why most people tend to just leave shared alone since it doesn't really work as intended.